# declaring state in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having issues with adding the following code into a freshly created reactJS + Material-UI app

code to be integrated

```
state = { icon: true }

handleClick = e => {
    const { icon } = this.state
    this.setState({ icon: !icon })   
}

render() {
    const { icon } = this.state
    return(
        <i className='large material-icons' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            { icon ? 'add' : 'remove'}
        </i>
    )

}
```

My code (that works)

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
  }));


  function Nav() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Nav;
```

What I want to do is make a button that when pressed it changes the icon I have tried the following

```
function Nav() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const state = { icon: true }

    handleClick = e => {
      const { icon } = this.state
      this.setState({ icon: !icon })   
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            <i className='large material-icons' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            { icon ? 'add' : 'remove'}
        </i>

          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're trying to create a state in a functional component, in previous versions of react you cannot have access to the states in functional components they were also used to called (stateless components). but after the latest version of React i.e: 16.8 you can now use state in your functional components as well using a new concept HOOkS. [Read more about react hooks from here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) Coming towards your problem, material-ui have ended the support for class in their newer versions i.e v4, so now they only have functional components and they use react hooks. Here you can do two things,

1. learn about react hooks and then use them in your metarial-ui components to write your custom logic.
2. or use the older version of material ui i.e: v3.9 where you can have access to the class components.

You can solve tthe current problem like this, (using hooks)

```
    function Nav() {
const classes = useStyles();
const [icon,setIcon] = useState(true)

const handleClick = e => {
  setIcon(!icon)   
}

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
          News
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        <i className='large material-icons' onClick={handleClick}>
        { icon ? 'add' : 'remove'}
    </i>

      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
);
```

}

make sure you've react version 16.8 if you wants to use hooks. also don't forget to import useState from react i.e:`import React,{useState} from 'react`

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting this error Line 28:  'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef 

Solved by making it a function handleClick(){
      setIcon(!icon)   
    }

and then removing this.

Comment: yes because you cannot have access to this inside a function, we use this in a class component, i've edited my answer now try to remove this where you're calling the handle click funct and while declaring it declare it inside a variable

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line, as you don't have access to `this` inside functional component.

```
<i className='large material-icons' onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

to this,

```
<i className='large material-icons' onClick={handleClick}>
```